# else if condition in js render template

Tags: javascript, jsrender

Hi i have use the following code snippet in js render template.

```
{{if Expanded}}e-gridtreerowexpand {{else (!Expanded)&&(HasChildGridRecords)}} e-gridtreerowcollapse {{/if}}
```

In this else condition did not work. Where Expanded, HasChildGridRecords are the properties present in the data object to be rendered.

How to resolve this propblem.

Answer (score 3):

That should work. (Though it is redundant to put `(!Expanded)` since you already tested that in the if).

You can write

```
{{if Expanded}}
  e-gridtreerowexpand
{{else HasChildGridRecords}}
  e-gridtreerowcollapse
{{/if}}
```

(No need for the parens either)

If Expanded is true you get the first block rendered.

If HasChildGridRecords truey, and Expanded is falsey, you get the second block.

Comment: hi Borris , 
is it supporting else if syntax ?

Comment: @LakshithaUdara: Yes, {{else someExpression}} behaves as 'else if' and {{else}} behaves as 'else' See last section of http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag.